# CGI::Application, hidden form value overwritten

Tags: perl, cgi

I am going through the basic example for [CGI::Application](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CGI-Application/lib/CGI/Application.pm#USAGE_EXAMPLE) but when I try to add a 3rd mode, it seems the query object is refusing to use my supplied value.

**webapp.cgi**:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
  use webapp;
  my $webapp = WebApp->new();
  $webapp->run();
```

**webapp.pm:**

```
package WebApp;
use base 'CGI::Application';

sub setup {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->start_mode('mode1');
    $self->mode_param('rm');
    $self->run_modes(
        'mode1' => 'do_stuff',
        'mode2' => 'do_more_stuff',
        'mode3' => 'do_something_else'
        );
}


sub do_stuff {
    my $self = shift;
    my $q = $self->query();

    my $output = '';
    $output .= $q->start_html(-title => 'Widget Search Form');
    $output .= $q->start_form();
    $output .= $q->textfield(-name => 'widgetcode');
    $output .= $q->hidden(-name => 'rm', -value => 'mode2');
    $output .= $q->submit();
    $output .= $q->end_form();
    $output .= $q->end_html();

    return $output;
}

sub do_more_stuff {
        my $self = shift;
        my $q = $self->query();
        my $widgetcode = $q->param("widgetcode");
        my $output = '';
        $output .= $q->start_html(-title => 'List of Matching Widgets');    
        $output .= $q->start_form();
        $output .= $q->textfield(-name => 'widgetcode');
        $output .= $q->hidden(-name => 'rm', -value => 'mode3'); 
                                                     # ^^^^^^ 
                                                     # this value is being ignored
        $output .= $q->submit();
        $output .= $q->end_form();      
        $output .= $q->end_html();

        return $output;
}

sub do_something_else {
        my $self = shift;
        my $q = $self->query();
        my $widgetcode = $q->param("widgetcode");
        my $output = '';
        $output .= $q->start_html(-title => 'Widgets details');  
        $output .= $q->start_form();
        $output .= $q->textfield(-name => 'widgetcode');
        $output .= $q->hidden(-name => 'rm', -value => 'mode4');
        $output .= $q->submit();
        $output .= $q->end_form();
        $output .= $q->end_html();
        return $output;
}

1;
```

So it works fine to load the first page (mode1), it gives me the form, and I can submit it and reach the second page (mode2), but I cannot reach mode3, because the `rm` param is being set to "mode2", despite the fact that, as you can read above, I am setting it to "mode3". That means I am sent back to mode2 again. I can change the `rm` to be `rm2` or something else and then the right value gets picked up, but obviously that's not helpful, since the `rm` variable is what is used to set the mode.

I don't have experience with `CGI.pm` (which supplies the `query` object) and as you can tell, I am only just starting to learn CGI::Application, so I don't know what is going on or how to solve this.

Comment: Note that the module's package and file name *must* be identical on Linux machines, and it is as well to follow that convention on Windows. So the file should be `WebApp.pm`, the package should be `WebApp`, you should `use WebApp`, and create a new object with `my $webapp = WebApp->new`

Comment: hi Borodin, this _is_ on a linux box, and yeah, I am aware of the convention, I just happened to have saved it before realizing I didn't capitalize it the same way. Since it worked, and it was just to test the sample code, I didn't really bother. Thanks for the reminder in any case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the perlmonks had the wisdom: [Hidden fields using CGI](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=344427)

> You can use the -override parameter to force it to use the default value.

Which in my case would be used as follows:

```
$output .= $q->hidden(-name => 'rm', -value => 'mode3' , -override => 1);
```

Hope that helps whoever finds this question through a search, since this isn't obvious at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it appears that the `hidden` method will use the current form value if one exists instead of what you specify as the default.  This could be observed with the following code when accessing a view with `?rm=mode2`:

```
$output .= $q->hidden(-name => 'rm', -value => 'mode3'); # Prints mode2
$q->param('rm' => 'mode3');
$output .= $q->hidden(-name => 'rm'); # Print mode3
```

As you found, the best solution is to use the override flag as documented in [`CGI #Form Elements`](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html#FORM-ELEMENTS)

```
$output .= $q->hidden(-name => 'rm', -value => 'mode3', -override => 1); # Print mode3
```

Comment: It's by design.  With most form fields, you want to be able to specify a default, but if the user stays on the same page after a submission, you want the fields autofilled with the user supplied data.  hidden fields are treated the same as a bit of a carry over.  Hard to say what the preferred logic should be, but recognizing that all form fields are treated the same probably simplifies things.  So just gotta remember the override flag.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange, it's a definite trip-up for beginners, and increases resistance to adoption. I can foresee getting bit by this one in the future again. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Actually, I expect it comes up very rarely.  Here's the thing, the examples they suggest are a bit contrived.  Most coders are going to have the validation for a form on the same "mode" as the form.  You want to be able to still display the original form with error messages if necessary.  Only upon a confirmed success do you go to a new "mode" or form.  So the fact that this example streamlined things to have the validation on a different mode rarely happens, and was only done so they could show you the concept of different modes.  Not to demonstrate good coding practices.

Comment: ahh, I think I see what you mean. I will have to learn a bit more as to how it all works to properly understand the choice of behavior here. Thanks